# Play audio file in a sequence in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have two functions. First one loops list of names for audio to be played, and the second one is the actual player function. The problem is that it plays only the last one. It does not play one by one waiting till the next is finished. How it possible to perform in a sequence? I tried to add: dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { }) ... still does not work. Any possible solution. Thank you in advance!

```
func startGame(){
            audioPlay("NowListen")
            for i in 0...self.soundArray.count - 1 {
                    print(self.soundArray[i])
                    self.audioPlay(self.soundArray[i])
            }

        }



func audioPlay(name: String){
            var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(name)", ofType: "mp3")!)
            print(alertSound)
            // try to play sound
            do{
                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
                self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                self.audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **AVQueuePlayer** ( init it with Items at the start and it will play in queue, one after another ) class instead of **AVAudioPlayer**.

In your Start Game, you can do following:

```
    var audioItems: [AVPlayerItem] = []
    for audioName in soundsArray {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioName, ofType: "mp3")!)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
        audioItems.append(item)
    }

    let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: audioItems)
    player.play()
```

Comment: Can you provide simple examples, please

Comment: save player somewhere, otherwise it will be deallocated after this method/block/function

Comment: Thank you! I save it outside the function, as global variable, seems to work!